# How to create crawable ajax pages that navigate to the previous even of ajax on clicking back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

How to create crawable ajax pages that navigate to the previous even of ajax on clicking back button.

I am able to do that through history.pushstate. But **Problem ** is that when I try to press the back button the url appears to be good but the content remains the same.
Kindly tell me what to do as I have already tried many alternatives but was'nt able to accomplish it

I have a form in Laravel same like :

```
<form class="navbar-form" id="searchform" name="searchform" role="form" @if(isset($searchpage))  onsubmit="results()"
      @else  action="{{URL::to('searchna')}}" @endif method="get" onkeyup="suggest()" >
    <input id="prompt" type="text" class="form-control"  name="key" id="enter" @if(isset($key)) value="{{$key}}" @endif
           placeholder="Search for users" >

                <select class="form-control">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">Recent Entries</option>
                    <option value="1">Oldest Entries</option>
                    <option value="2">Maximum Wage</option>
                    <option value="3">Minimum Wage</option>
                </select>
        <div id="suggest"></div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>
    <div id="searchresults"> </div>
</form>
```

Also in my java script i have

```
<script> 
function results(){
    ready();
    //showSearchResults();
    event.preventDefault();
    //loadingHide();

    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var key=$('input[name=key]').val();
    /*if (key==""){
        $("#result").hide();
        $("#tableusers").show();
    }*/
    //else{
    var forbrowser=$("#searchform").serialize();
        $.get('searchna',{key: key, _token:CSRF_TOKEN}, function(data){
            //showSearchResults();
            //document.title =key+ " | Search";
            //$("#result").html(data);
            //$("#result").load("searchna" + " #result")
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
            $( "#result" ).load( "searchna?"+ forbrowser + " #result" );
            var state = { 'key': key /*, 'user_id': 5*/ };
            var title =key+ " | Search";
            var url ="searchna?" + forbrowser;
            history.pushState(state, title, url);
            //history.replaceState(state, title, url);
            //alert("new location: "+window.location.href + "<br> host name : " + window.location.hostname + "<br> History : " + window.history);

            //searchna?key=he&_token=OVyWtIFhup2vjOz8H6uAJ08NAxtuuLbWUoSlxcwI
        });
   // }
}
</script>
```

I need to create a search same like olx.com. http://www.olx.com.pk/all-results/q-samsung-s4/

which does not reloads the page and instead loads a part of the web page and on clicking back button of the browser there are displayed the previous ajax action. This is somewhat we call URL hashing or ajax crawable web pages.

Comment: Long story short: Google sees your AJAX web pages just like your browser. Source: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html. Other crawlers probably don't. The linked article links to Google's old suggestions about that which probably still work with other crawlers. When it comes to search results however, this might be a different story.

Comment: I want to increase the performance thats why I am using ajax for search results

Comment: This question is actually two at once: you ask how to properly implement history on AJAX pages and how to make AJAX pages crawlable. I asnwered the first question in last comment. As for working with history correctly, please refer to projects like history.js: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: I just need the crawable web page ajax.

Comment: On each page navigation on ajax call the content must change and then when we press the back butto the previous state ust be retrieved with unique bookmarkable url

Comment: As I said, see history.js.